# Spring ignores property file in current directory using that in CLASSPATH instead

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring properties file defined as:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>lanchecker.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

According to 23.3 in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html:

> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:
>
> A /config subdir of the current directory.
>
> The current directory
>
> A classpath /config package
>
> The classpath root
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).

During development this file resides on the CLASSPATH, at /src/main/resources, and is resolved fine. After packaging I provide another in the current directory but it is ignored and the one from the CLASSPATH still used.

What have I missed here please?

Comment: We may need to know more about your file structure to be able to help.  Where is the spring config file? where is the properties file? etc

Comment: The properties files is, as above, at /src/main/resources during development and in the current directory at runtime after packaging/assembly. spring.xml is at /src/main/resources.

Comment: So, at runtime, your file is not found in a folder called `/config`, the current directory (same as the spring.xml file) or a package called `config`?

Comment: At runtime two property files exist: the one embedded within the jar on the classpath at /src/main/resources, and one in the current directory where the execution is started.  According to the reference the one in the current directory should take precedence.  When I test it the one embedded in the jar is still being used.  None of the other cases exist.

Comment: Right, but IIRC the 'current' directory refers to the directory where the spring.xml file is (not where the execution is started) - that's what I am trying to assert

Comment: Ah.  Hadn't caught that overload.  Are you sure though?  It seems to go against the whole ethos of external configuration and the introduction to Section 23, viz:

 "You can bundle an application.properties inside your jar that provides a sensible default name. When running in production, an application.properties can be provided outside of your jar that overrides name; and for one-off testing, you can launch with a specific command line switch (e.g. java -jar app.jar --name="Spring")."

How do I actually acheive this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92296/discussion-between-ochi-and-ian-worthington).

Comment: That section only applies to the default `application.properties` loaded by default NOT for other property files defined by you. Drop your own properties, add the content of that file to `application.properties` (or rename the file) then at runtime place another `application.properties` in the same directory it will work.

Comment: Also if you are using plain Spring it won;t work either as that is a Spring Boot specific feature!...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:lanchecker.properties</value>
            <value>file:${user.dir}/lanchecker.properties</value>   <!-- file values will override classpath if exists -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If both exist it will read the resource on the classpath first, then replace the values there with anything in the file.

If neither exist they'll just be a nasty traceback at some later stage when the property values come to be used. There are though some INFO log messages to help solve this.  No pleasant, but it's the best I've been able to come up with today